# Separar dados de um arquivo txt

Tags: python, slice

Tenho um arquivo relativamente grande de dados, que retirei de uma máquina de marcar ponto, porém ela vem da seguinte maneira:

```
00003000527005792012635570932000219305130720170713
00003000527005792012635570932000219305130720170713
```

Gostaria de separar estes dados em colunas para que eu possa exportar ao Excel:

```
00003000527005792 - numero de serie do relógio | 012635570932 - Numero do PIS | 000219305 - NSR  |13 - dia | 07 - Mês | 2017 - Ano |07 - hora |13 - minuto
```

Ficando assim:

```
00003000527005792 012635570932 000219305 13 07 2017 07 13
```

Bom, até o momento eu consegui ler os dados usando este código:

```
arquivo = open('DATA.txt', 'r')
for linha in arquivo:
    print(linha)
arquivo.close()
```

Como consigo aplicar o `slice` neste contexto? Pois eu consigo fazer isso em uma frase, mas não sei aplica-lo em varias linhas

Comment: print(linha[1:17] + ';' + linha[18:29] + ';' + linha[30:38] + ';' + linha[39:40] + ';' + linha[41:42] + ';' + linha[43:46] + ';' + linha[47:48] + ';' + linha[49:50] )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partindo do princípio que cada linha vai ter sempre a mesma formatação, número de digitos etc...

Não acho boa ideia separares por espaços, visto que os nomes das colunas têm espaços, neste caso vou separar por ";".

Podes fazer assim:

```
cols = ['numero de serie do relógio', 'Numero do PIS', 'NSR', 'Dia', 'Mês', 'Ano', 'Hora', 'Minuto']
novos_dados = ''
with open('DATA.txt') as f:
    for l in f: # o slice vai ser feito na linha abaixo para cada linha
        novos_dados += '{};{};{};{};{};{};{};{}\n'.format(l[:17], l[17:29], l[29:38], l[38:40], l[40:42], l[42:46], l[46:48], l[48:])
content = '{}\n{}'.format(';'.join(cols), novos_dados)

# gravar content em um csv
print(content, file=open('novos_dados.csv', 'w'))
```

Em princípio o `.csv` vai abrir por default no excel, e neste caso deves escolher o separador ";" quando importares o ficheiro `novos_dados.csv`

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/DangerousFirsthandSpringbok)

Comment: Isso mesmo que precisava, obrigado amigo. Agora consigo fazer para outras aplicações também. Me explique uma coisa, quando você diz parar separar usando o `;` no Excel ele entende isso como sendo colunas?

Comment: E o que é `content`?

Comment: Exato @WSS, quando abres um ficheiro csv normalmente por default a aplicação associada é o excel, nesse momento vai te ser pedido para escolheres o separador que queres para dividir as colunas, neste caso o `;`. `content` é a variável que vai conter todo o conteúdo que vai ser gravado no ficheiro, podes fazer um `print(content)` para veres melhor

Comment: Testei aqui. Agora ficou claro o código. Obrigado @Miguel.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é utilizar regex dessa forma:

```
import re
with open(arquivo) as fp:
    data = list([
        re.match(r'^(?P<serial_number>\d{17})(?P<PIS>\d{12})(?P<NSR>\d{9})(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<year>\d{4})(?P<hour>\d{2})(?P<minute>\d{2})', linha).groupdict()
        for linha in fp])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('stack.txt', widths=[17,12,9,2,2,4,2,2], header=None, index_col=None)

df.to_csv('stack2.csv', index = False, header=False)
```